# app.user variable empty (or not available?) in twig custom error message

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

According to [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#app), the variable `app` is available "everywhere" for twig templates. I want to use `app.user` in a custom error message, but this variable does not actually seem to be available within these templates while in `prod` mode; it IS available in `dev` mode.

Example code:

```
// project/templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <div>
        <h1>Page not found</h1>

        <p>
            Hello {{ app.user.name }}, {% <---- DOES NOT WORK %}

            The requested page couldn't be located. Checkout for any URL
            misspelling.
        </p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is just a simple example, but illustrates the point. I've also tried to use

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
   // do something fancy
{% endif %}
```

and this also does not work. It also does not matter whether I extend `base.html.twig` or pull in the `parent()`, in all cases it does not work. I get no error messages at all.  I have cleared by cache.

Any ideas about how to get this information to my template in `prod` mode?

Answer (score 3):

I found in the documentation that the problem I describe is by design. From the docs:

> Security & 404 Pages¶
>
> Due to the order of how routing and security are
> loaded, security information will not be available on your 404 pages.
> This means that it will appear as if your user is logged out on the
> 404 page (it will work while testing, but not on production).

The answer is to create my own exception controller (or extend the default `ExceptionController`).